# How can I simplify this redundant code?

Tags: php, variables, refactoring, simplify, variable-variables

Can someone please help me simpling this redundant piece of code?

```
if (isset($to) === true)
{
    if (is_string($to) === true)
    {
        $to = explode(',', $to);
    }

    $to = array_filter(filter_var_array(preg_replace('~[<>]|%0[ab]|[[:cntrl:]]~i', '', $to), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
}

if (isset($cc) === true)
{
    if (is_string($cc) === true)
    {
        $cc = explode(',', $cc);
    }

    $cc = array_filter(filter_var_array(preg_replace('~[<>]|%0[ab]|[[:cntrl:]]~i', '', $cc), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
}

if (isset($bcc) === true)
{
    if (is_string($bcc) === true)
    {
        $bcc = explode(',', $bcc);
    }

    $bcc = array_filter(filter_var_array(preg_replace('~[<>]|%0[ab]|[[:cntrl:]]~i', '', $bcc), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
}

if (isset($from) === true)
{
    if (is_string($from) === true)
    {
        $from = explode(',', $from);
    }

    $from = array_filter(filter_var_array(preg_replace('~[<>]|%0[ab]|[[:cntrl:]]~i', '', $from), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
}
```

I tried using variable variables but without success (it's been a long time since I've used them).

Comment: Good question. Sensible one, unlike most of them here.

Comment: Duplicate of [Variable functions and variable names in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617976/variable-functions-and-variable-names-in-php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable variables:

```
$vars = array('to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'from');
foreach ($vars as $varname) {
    if (isset($$varname)) {
        if (is_string($$varname)) {
            $$varname = explode(',', $$varname);
        }
        $$varname = array_filter(filter_var_array(preg_replace('~[<>]|%0[ab]|[[:cntrl:]]~i', '', $$varname), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
    }
}
```

Regular (Without using variable variables):

```
$vars = compact('to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'from'); 
foreach ($vars as $name => &$var) {
    if (is_string($var)) {
        $var = explode(',', $var);
    }
    $var = array_filter(filter_var_array(preg_replace('~[<>]|%0[ab]|[[:cntrl:]]~i', '', $var), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
}
extract ($vars);
```

Note, you don't need isset, because compact will only import variables that are set.  All others are ignored...

BTW: You don't need the === true.  isset() or is_string() will always return a boolean.  So the === true is redundant...

Comment: I'd just like to add that it's necessary to do `compact($to, $cc, $bcc, $from)` for it to skip null variables, otherwise we still need the `isset()` check.

Answer (score 2):

You could do (untested)

```
$vars = array($from, $to, $cc, $bcc);

foreach ($vars as $var)
        {
        $var = explode(',', $var);
        ....
        ...
        }

$from = $vars[0];
$to = $vars[1];
$cc = $vars[2];
$bcc = $vars[3];
```

Comment: I think that you have to make `$var` a reference, with a `&`

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a function?

```
function validate($str) {
    if (isset($str) === true)
    {
        if (is_string($str) === true)
        {
            $str = explode(',', $str);
        }

        $str = array_filter(filter_var_array(preg_replace('~[<>]|%0[ab]|[[:cntrl:]]~i', '', $str), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
    }
    return $str;
}

$to = validate($to);
$cc = validate($cc);
$bcc = validate($bcc);
$from = validate($from);
```

Answer (score 1):

I could do this:

You can probably create a function for that:

```
function checkIt($var)
{
    if (isset($var) === true)
    {
        if (is_string($var) === true)
        {
          $var = explode(',', $var);
        }

        $to = explode(',', $var);
        $to = array_filter(filter_var_array(preg_replace('~[<>]|%0[ab]|[[:cntrl:]]~i', '', $to), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
    }

    return $to;
}
```

And now you can pass your variables to this function.

Comment: But then it won't filter if the variable isn't a string, as in the OP.

Comment: @adam: But there is no `else` condition that if it is not a string process it otherwise. He is only interested in string so the code executes only if it is string not otherwise.

Comment: Because there's no else condition, it explodes it if it's a string but filters it irrespective of whether it's a string or not. Have another look.

Comment: @adam: Rightly spotted, fixed :)

Comment: The `checkIt` function returns an undefined value `$to` in the case where $var is set but isn't a string.

Comment: @David: It won't, it is assigned to `$to` at line: `$to = explode(',', $var);`

Answer (score 1):

Just stick the values in an array and iterate over it.

```
function cleanEmails($value) {
    if (is_string($value)) {
        $value = explode(',', $value);
    }
    return array_filter(filter_var_array(preg_replace('~[<>]|%0[ab]|[[:cntrl:]]~i', '', $value), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
}

$fields = array();
if (isset($to)) {
    $fields['to'] = $to;
}
if (isset($from)) {
    $fields['from'] = $from;
}
if (isset($cc)) {
    $fields['cc'] = $cc;
}
if (isset($bcc)) {
    $fields['bcc'] = $bcc;
}
$result = array_map('cleanEmails', $fields);
```

The end result will be a 2 dimensional array, first index will be the fields that were set, second index will be the respective email addresses...

Answer (score 1):

Even without going the full variable variables route, you could simplify this a lot just by putting the checks into a common function, and then doing:

```
$to = cleanup_email_addrs($to);
$cc = cleanup_email_addrs($cc);
$bcc = cleanup_email_addrs($bcc);
$from = cleanup_email_addrs($from);
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you can get rid of the `isset() === true`; `isset()` returns either `true` or `false`.

And of course put it in a function as all your `if` statements seem to do the same thing, but that´s been mentioned before...

By the way, does your `array_filter` line work if the input is not an `array()`?

If not, you need to include that statement inside the `if (is_string())` statement.